# ASP.NET Pass multiple checkbox values into a SELECT query

Tags: asp.net

I am working on displaying a students timetable based on possible Module choices. Each time a check box is selected I want to pass through the value selected "ModuleId" to use in a SELECT query to display the timetable for all modules selected. So if a user selects 3 check boxes the 'ModuleId' from each row selected will be passed into the SELECT query.

I don't know how to store each selected "ModuleId" and add it into my select query.

Below is how I retrieve the checked value:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="40px"></ItemStyle>
          <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRow" runat="server" ToolTip='<%# Eval("ModuleId") %>' OnCheckedChanged="module_Changed" />
         </ItemTemplate>
<asp:TemplateField>
```

Below is my method to display the value in a label (just for testing purposes):

```
     protected void module_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         // Retrieve the check box ModuleId value to add to my SELECT query
         string moduleid = ((CheckBox)sender).ToolTip;
     }
```

Below is my method which contains the select query to display the timetable:

```
 public String[] getModulesAtCurrentSlot(int timeslotInt, String moduleID, String Day)
        {
            List<String> modulesList = new List<string>();
            if (conn.State.ToString() == "Closed")
            {
                conn.Open();
            }
            SqlCommand newCmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            newCmd.Connection = conn;
            newCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            newCmd.CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT Module.ModuleCode,ClassType.ClassTypeName,Convert(time,Class.StartTime), Convert(time,Class.EndTime),Building.BuildingName,RoomCode.RoomCode,Class.Color" +
                     " FROM Class INNER JOIN Module ON Class.ModuleId = Module.ModuleId INNER JOIN RoomCode ON Class.RoomCodeId = RoomCode.RoomcodeId INNER JOIN Building ON RoomCode.BuildingId = Building.BuildingId INNER JOIN Days ON Class.DayId = Days.DayID INNER JOIN ClassType ON Class.ClassTypeId = ClassType.ClassTypeId WHERE " +
                     " Module.ModuleId = " + moduleID + " AND Convert(Date,StartTime) = '" + Day + "' AND " + timeslotInt.ToString() + " BETWEEN ClassScheduleStartTimeId and ClassScheduleEndTimeId";
            SqlDataReader dr = newCmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                String current = "<div class='slot' " + (!dr.IsDBNull(6) ? "style=\"background-color: " + dr.GetString(6) + ";\"" : "") + ">";
                current += "<div class='line1'>" + dr.GetString(0) + "&nbsp;" + dr.GetString(1) + "</div>";// +"<br />";
                current += "<div class='line2'>" + dr.GetTimeSpan(2).ToString().TrimEnd('0').TrimEnd('0').TrimEnd(':') + "&nbsp;-&nbsp;" + dr.GetTimeSpan(3).ToString().TrimEnd('0').TrimEnd('0').TrimEnd(':') + "</div>";// +"<br />";
                current += "<div class='line3'>" + dr.GetString(4) + "&nbsp;" + dr.GetString(5) + "</div>";
                current += "</div>";
                modulesList.Add(current);
            }
            conn.Close();
            return modulesList.ToArray();
        }
```

On a previous page where the timetable is only displaying data for one ModuleId  I've used the below query string to pass through the value.

```
 String module_ID = "2";
        if (Request.QueryString["module"] != null)
        {
            module_ID = Request.QueryString["module"];
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Missing ?module=XX from url :(");
            Response.End();// EndRequest;
        }
```

DBAccess.cs screenshot:
[image: DBAccess.cs screenshot]

Error screenshot:
[image: Errors screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you could have a session variable that contains a List of strings which holds all of the selected moduleID's

You could then use module_Changed event to add or remove moduleIDs from this List and then call getModulesAtCurrentSlot in a loop for each moduleid in the list and concatenate the returned string[]s into one longer string[] or List which you then display.

there may be some errors in the code below as I'm just doing it from memory but it should give you an idea!

```
protected void module_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> lst;
    if( Session["lst"]!=null)
        lst = (List<string>)Session["lst"];
    else
           Session.Add("lst", new List<string>());


     // Retrieve the check box ModuleId value to add to my SELECT query
     string moduleid = ((CheckBox)sender).ToolTip;

    // add your own code to check if checkbox is checked or unchecked to see if you need to add or remove the ID from the list

     // to add
     if(lst.Contains(moduleid) == false)
         lst.Add(moduleid);

     // to remove - add your own code

     List<string> lstResult = new List<string>();
     foreach(var moduleID in lst)
     {
         lstResult.Add(getModulesAtCurrentSlot(timeslotInt, moduleID, Day));
     }

     // do something to display lstResult
     // e.g. drag a Gridview control on your aspx page and bind the results list to it - this is just to give you a rough idea but you'll need to play around with it to get it to work as you want, and hopefully learn something in the process ;)
     Gridview1.DataSource = lstResult;
     Gridview1.Databind();

 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for providing the above code. I read through your comments and code and I think its a smart idea to use a session to pass through a string containing all ModuleId's. I am quite new to c# programming and so I am not totally sure how to pass through all ModuleId's selected as a session. Ive added code above from a previous page.

Comment: no problem, make sure you save your updated list back to the session too otherwise you'll lose it

Comment: I have tried to implement this code in but it is throwing an error with the following: Session.Add(new List<string>)); . I understand what it is you are trying to do now. I just don't know how all the ModuleId's selected are passed through on the list. I get you use a foreach loop but all selected ModuleId's will need to be displayed in the timetable at once. The getModulesAtCurrentSlot will only replace the ModuleId with one value. Please advise :)

Comment: Session.Add("lst", new List<string>());

Comment: Many thanks. Could we continue this in conversation please if you have time?

Comment: i've gotta go out now but i've added some extra code to give you some clues

Comment: Thank you I will try that now. I am getting the error "The name 'timeslotInt' and 'Day' does not exist in the current context". The actual getModulesAtCurrentSlot method is located in a separate .cs file so Ive used dba.getModulesAtCurrentSlot... to reference the method but I'm still getting those errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142348/discussion-between-dcraven-and-damo).